# In NetBeans IDE 6.9.1, can I remove the auto-correct-like functions?

Tags: java, coding-style, formatting, netbeans-6.9, spacing

Yes, I know that sounds very very vague, but say I begin typing a program:
    public class programname
and then I hit the return key to insert a { at the far left.  The program automatically makes it tab over.  Additionally, when I hit the { key, my insertion point goes down a line, and snaps to the left side without any tab-space.  It looks like this:

```
import java.text.*;
public class program18

{
```

This is annoying, because my personal habit is to arrange my code blocks like this:

```
import java.text.*
public class program18
{
    //statements go here
}
```

and NetBeans kills my "flow" when I need to stop and correct the spacing issues.  Occasionally, NetBeans even arranges brackets like this:

```
public static void methodname()
    {
    //statements here
        }
```

That really sets off my OCD.

Is there a way to prevent this?

Comment: That is not normal behaviour; you might try a reinstall or upgrade.

Comment: This is on a school computer, I'm not an Administrator on the computer/network, nor do I have the password for the NetBeans account, although it has been asking me for it lately; it doesn't seem to do any harm just clicking cancel every time.

Answer (score 0):

The formatting settings are in **Tools : Options** dialog on the **Java : Formatting** tab. Unfortunately, I don't see any way to pick a standard set of rules from a list, so you'll need to fix them all by hand.

BTW, the latest version of NetBeans is 7.3. Ask your network administrator to upgrade to a version from this decade.